# Cómo Diferenciar el SerialNumber del Disco Duro de la pc

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Estoy desarrrollando una app en Embarcadero 10.3.3 c++. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
...
curDir = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia";   // Win32_DiskDrive
srcfile = curDir + L"";
objs = svc.OleFunction("ExecQuery", srcfile);
n = objs.OlePropertyGet("Count");
if(n){...}
...
```

La consulta anterior me devuelve un arreglo de medios tantos los usbs como las torres de cd, Disco Duro , etc... Necesito diferenciar de todos ellos cual es el ***SerialNumber*** del disco duro donde está instalado el Sistema Operativo.